# Error:(4, 42) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'cardBackgroundColor' with value '?android:attr/colorBackgroundFloating')

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Good day guys,

May i know why my recycler cardview message log shown this error? 
Does anyone encounter this error before?

```
D:\New folder\DrawerWithSwipeTabs\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v23\values-v23.xml

Error:(4, 42) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'cardBackgroundColor' with value '?android:attr/colorBackgroundFloating').

Error:(4, 42) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'cardBackgroundColor' with value '?android:attr/colorBackgroundFloating').
```

It automatically pop up to  D:\New folder\DrawerWithSwipeTabs\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v23\values-v23.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="CardView" parent="Base.CardView">
        <item name="cardBackgroundColor">?android:attr/colorBackgroundFloating</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**build.gradle （Project）**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**build.gradle (Module:app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.androidbelieve.drawerwithswipetabs"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.1'

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
parent="Base.CardView"
```

this parent class is not introduce in sdk version 22.
To implement this you need to change your minSdk version and library version to sdk-version 23.

somthing like this.

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.androidbelieve.drawerwithswipetabs"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
}

dependencies {

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.1'
}
```